# Form Validation Works on one script but not the other and I cannot figure out why! JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, validation

I am trying to learn how to do form validation and figure out how to do certain things, I tried it on one of the scripts to see if I can put rules on the name and password. Then later went to my original form script to apply the validation form to it and I cant get it to work. Any idea why?

Form validation trial:

```
const name = document.getElementById('userID')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const errorElement = document.getElementById('error')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  let messages = []
  if (name.value === '' || name.value == null) {
    messages.push('Name is required')
  }

  if(name.value.length <= 6) {
    alert('name must be longer than 6 characters')
  }

  if (password.value.length <= 6) {
    messages.push('Password must be longer than 6 characters')
  }

  if (password.value.length >= 20) {
    messages.push('Password must be less than 20 characters')
  }

  if (password.value === 'password') {
    messages.push('Password cannot be password')
  }

  if (messages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    errorElement.innerText = messages.join(', ')
  }
})
```

script it worked on (But I just need to replace the ID's for it to work)

```
<script defer src="formCheck.js"></script>
</head>

<div id="error"></div>
<form id="form" action="/" method="GET">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" name="password" type="password">
  </div>
  <input class="btn" type = "submit" value="upload" name = "UploadButton">
</form>
```

My original script that I cannot get it to work on:

```
<head>
    <script defer src="formCheck.js"></script>
    <title> Create User!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">
</head>

<div class="userForm">


    <h1>
    Create User!
    </h1>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form method = "post"  id="form" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="/getUserInfo" name = "form">

    <!-- /AddUser/:userID/:userName/:userGender/:userSeniority/:userHouse/:userLogin/:userPassword -->

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User ID:</label>
        <input type = "text" id="userID" name = "userID" value = "" placeholder="Enter ID" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User Name:</label>
        <input type = "text" id="userName" name = "userName" value = "" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User Gender:</label>
        <select type = "text" placeholder = "Choose Gender" data-style="btn-info" name="userGender" required>

            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User Nationality:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "userNationality" value = "" placeholder="Enter Nationality" required>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="txtb">
        <label>User Occupation:</label>
        <select type = "text" placeholder = "Choose Occupation" data-style="btn-info" name="userOccupation">

            <option value="a">A</option>
            <option value="b">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
            <option value="d">D</option>
            <option value="e">E</option>

        </select>
    </div> -->

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User House:</label>
        <select type = "text" placeholder = "Choose House" data-style="btn-info" name="userHouse" required>

            <option value="0">Red</option>
            <option value="1">Blue</option>
            <option value="2">Green</option>
            <option value="3">Purple</option>

        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>User Login:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "userLogin" value = "" placeholder="Enter Login" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb1">
        <label>User Property:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "userProperty" value = "" placeholder="Enter Property" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb1">
        <label>User Department:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "userDepartment" value = "" placeholder="Enter Department" required>
    </div>

    <div class="txtb1">
        <label>User Position:</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "userPosition" value = "" placeholder="Enter Position" required>
    </div>   

    <div class="txtb1">
        <label>User Date Of Joining:</label>

        <label>Month:</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="12" step="1" name="userMonth" oninput="(validity.valid)||(value='');" required>

        <label>Day:</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="31" step="1" name="userDay" oninput="(validity.valid)||(value='');" required>

        <label>Year:</label>
        <input type="number" min="2020" max="2999" step="1" name="userYear" oninput="(validity.valid)||(value='');" required>

    </div>

    <div class="txtb">
        <label>Profile Picture:</label>
        <input type = "file" name = "picture" required>
    </div>

    <input class="btn" type = "submit" value="upload" name = "UploadButton">

    </form>



    <form method = "get" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="/mainPage">   
        <input class = "btn" type = "submit" value="Main Page">
    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?  When you use your browser's debugging tools, what happens?  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  When you step through the code in your browser's script debugger, does each operation produce the result you expect?  Which operation first produces an error or unexpected result?

Comment: it doesnt run at all

Comment: If your JavaScript code isn't even executing when you load the page then you've structured something incorrectly, which we can't see from how it's formatted here in this question.  Maybe you forgot to wrap it in a `<script>` tag?  Maybe the tag is malformed?  Maybe something else?  If you can produce a complete and self-contained example that would be helpful.

Comment: You're loading the script in the head and executing it immediately. The elements in the body don't exist yet so it seems like nothing happens. The *defer* attribute does not guarantee that a script will run after the DOM is loaded, only that scripts will be executed in order.